# An efficient way to store and manipulate my variables in Javascript, using Objects?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have a program which involves taking some user imputed values on a web page. These values are then sent out via a serial port to some control electronics.

There are six different "zones" and these have 6 values associated with each of them which are all set on the page by the user and read and stored by javascript.

I had been using 6 arrays to store the data but I would like to now use objects as I think this will make the code more readable when I refer to and manipulate the data elsewhere on the page.

This gives me 6 objects with 6 properties each, so I have for example zone1.duration - zone1.repeat .... zone6.op

So is this a good and efficient way to store the values? Also I do need to harvest the data from the web page to start with and interpret it for other functions associated with the web page. Before I did this in a simple loop cycling through the different zones and I am not sure how to do this with the objects.

The code below illustrates what I would like to do to get the values loaded from the web page, the document.getElementById part does work as I used that before but I don't know the proper syntax to cycle through the different zones and assign the properties. I have shown my poor attempt on the first line only.

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++){   
        ('zone'+ i )["op"] = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'Operate').value;
        zone1["onHour"] = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'OnTimeH').value;
        zone1["onMinute"] = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'OnTimeM').value;
        zone1["duration"] = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'Duration').value;
        zone1["repeat"] = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'Repeat').value;
        zone1["ex"] = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'Extra').value;
        }
```

Hopefully this provides an idea of what I am trying to achieve. My questions are: Is this a good way to do it in the first place and if so what to I need to alter to get the above code to work. If not what would be a better way?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for an array of objects. For example:

```
var zones = [,{},{},{},{},{},{}];  // leading comma indicates element 0 not used.

for (i = 1; i < 7; i++){   
   zones[i].op = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'Operate').value;
   zones[i].onHour = document.getElementById('Z' + i + 'OnTimeH').value;

   // etc
}
```

Comment: That is all working very well but I just have a problem with the syntax of this line which I use elsewhere where I get a TypeError: zone[i] is undefined                                                    newAJAXCommand('pwms.cgi?aws=' + j + '&value=' + zone[i].onHour);

Comment: This might be as simple as using `zone[i]` when you should be using `zones[i]`. You might alternatively have a problem with the array being out of scope, or the index having the wrong value - possibly that's out of scope. I can't say without seeing the code. In any case, scope issues are a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I had changed to zone[i] in my code. But main idea of the object array is working very well. I will look into scope issues.